# Need to refresh the page to update the state and display it in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I made a shopping cart, when I click on the button 'add to cart' of an item it moves to local storage and I get those items from local storage and display it. But when I press the button it moves to cart but doesn't show unless I refresh the page. So how do I solve this issue. someone please help me...

My add to cart onclick function....

```
add_to_cart = (product) => {
    let cart_data = [];
    const booth_id = product.booth_id;
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart") !== null) {
        cart_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
        if (
            cart_data[booth_id] !== null &&
            cart_data[booth_id] !== undefined
        ) {
            console.log(cart_data[booth_id]);
            let already_added_products = cart_data[booth_id];
            product = { ...product, quantity: 1 };
            cart_data[booth_id] = [...already_added_products, product];
        } else {
            let booth_list = [];
            product = { ...product, quantity: 1 };
            cart_data[booth_id] = [...booth_list, product];
        }
    } else {
        let booth_list = [];
        product = { ...product, quantity: 1 };
        cart_data[booth_id] = [...booth_list, product];
    }

    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart_data));
};
```

This is how I render it....

```
<div className="product-container">
                                        {typeof this.state.products !=
                                            "undefined" &&
                                        this.state.products.length > 0
                                            ? this.state.products.map(
                                                  (product) => {
                                                      return (
                                                          <div
                                                              className="product-box"
                                                              key={
                                                                  product.id
                                                              }
                                                          >
                                                              <div className="bg-control">
                                                                  <div className="img-cover-wrap">
                                                                      <img
                                                                          src={
                                                                              product.image
                                                                          }
                                                                          alt={
                                                                              product.name
                                                                          }
                                                                      />
                                                                      <div className="hover-option">
                                                                          <a
                                                                              href="#!"
                                                                              onClick={() =>
                                                                                  this.add_to_cart(
                                                                                      product
                                                                                  )
                                                                              }
                                                                          >
                                                                              <i className="ri-shopping-cart-fill"></i>
                                                                              Add
                                                                          </a>
                                                                          <a
                                                                              href="#!"
                                                                              onClick={() =>
                                                                                  this.product_view(
                                                                                      product
                                                                                  )
                                                                              }
                                                                          >
                                                                              <i className="ri-eye-fill"></i>
                                                                              View
                                                                          </a>
                                                                      </div>
                                                                  </div>
                                                                  <div className="product-box-body">
                                                                      <h5 className="text-truncate">
                                                                          {
                                                                              product.name
                                                                          }
                                                                      </h5>
                                                                      <p>
                                                                          £{" "}
                                                                          {
                                                                              product.price
                                                                          }
                                                                      </p>
                                                                  </div>
                                                              </div>
                                                          </div>
                                                      );
                                                  }
                                              )
                                            : ""}
                                    </div>
```

This is how I display it in my cart (functions)...

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.cart_data();
}

show_cart = (val) => {
    this.setState({ booth_products: this.state.cart_data[val] });
};

cart_data = () => {
    let temp_cart = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem("cart"),
        (key, value) => {
            if (value !== null) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    );
    this.setState({ cart_data: temp_cart });
};

booth_num = (value) => {
    this.setState({ booth_id: value });
    this.show_cart(value);
};
```

My render for cart display...

```
<div className="product-cart-list">
                                                <ul
                                                    className="nav nav-pills mb-3"
                                                    id="pills-tab"
                                                    role="tablist"
                                                >
                                                    {this.state.cart_data
                                                        .length > 0
                                                        ? this.state.cart_data.map(
                                                              (
                                                                  booth,
                                                                  index
                                                              ) => {
                                                                  return (
                                                                      <li
                                                                          className="nav-item"
                                                                          role="presentation"
                                                                          key={
                                                                              index
                                                                          }
                                                                      >
                                                                          <a
                                                                              className="nav-link active"
                                                                              id="booth-one-tab"
                                                                              data-toggle="pill"
                                                                              href="#booth-one"
                                                                              role="tab"
                                                                              aria-controls="booth-one"
                                                                              aria-selected="true"
                                                                              onClick={() =>
                                                                                  this.booth_num(
                                                                                      index
                                                                                  )
                                                                              }
                                                                          >
                                                                              {"Booth " +
                                                                                  index}
                                                                          </a>
                                                                      </li>
                                                                  );
                                                              }
                                                          )
                                                        : ""}
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div
                                                className="tab-content"
                                                id="pills-tabContent"
                                            >
                                                <div
                                                    className="tab-pane fade show active"
                                                    id="booth-one"
                                                    role="tabpanel"
                                                    aria-labelledby="booth-one-tab"
                                                >
                                                    <div className="scrollbar-inner-wrap">
                                                        <div className="scrollbar-wrap">
                                                            {this.state
                                                                .booth_products
                                                                .length > 0
                                                                ? this.state.booth_products.map(
                                                                      (
                                                                          product,
                                                                          index
                                                                      ) => (
                                                                          <div
                                                                              className="product-cart-wrap"
                                                                              key={
                                                                                  index
                                                                              }
                                                                          >
                                                                              <div className="img-cover-wrap">
                                                                                  <img
                                                                                      src={
                                                                                          product.image
                                                                                      }
                                                                                      alt={
                                                                                          product.name
                                                                                      }
                                                                                  />
                                                                              </div>
                                                                              <div className="product-cart-body-wrap">
                                                                                  <h5 className="text-truncate">
                                                                                      {
                                                                                          product.name
                                                                                      }
                                                                                  </h5>
                                                                                  <div className="d-center mt-3">
                                                                                      <span className="price-wrap mr-3">
                                                                                          {"$" +
                                                                                              product.price}
                                                                                      </span>
                                                                                      <div className="product-count">
                                                                                          <form
                                                                                              action="#"
                                                                                              className="display-flex"
                                                                                          >
                                                                                              <div
                                                                                                  className="qtyminus"
                                                                                                  onClick={() =>
                                                                                                      this.decrease_quantity(
                                                                                                          product,
                                                                                                          index
                                                                                                      )
                                                                                                  }
                                                                                              >
                                                                                                  -
                                                                                              </div>
                                                                                              <input
                                                                                                  type="text"
                                                                                                  name="quantity"
                                                                                                  value="1"
                                                                                                  className="qty"
                                                                                                  value={
                                                                                                      product.quantity ||
                                                                                                      ""
                                                                                                  }
                                                                                                  onChange={() =>
                                                                                                      this
                                                                                                          .handleChange
                                                                                                  }
                                                                                              />
                                                                                              <div
                                                                                                  className="qtyplus"
                                                                                                  onClick={() =>
                                                                                                      this.increase_quantity(
                                                                                                          product,
                                                                                                          index
                                                                                                      )
                                                                                                  }
                                                                                              >
                                                                                                  +
                                                                                              </div>
                                                                                          </form>
                                                                                      </div>
                                                                                      <span className="qun-wrap mr-3">
                                                                                          Quantity
                                                                                      </span>
                                                                                      <button
                                                                                          type="button"
                                                                                          className="btn btn-cart-remove"
                                                                                      >
                                                                                          <i className="ri-close-circle-fill"></i>
                                                                                          <span
                                                                                              onClick={() =>
                                                                                                  this.remove_item(
                                                                                                      product,
                                                                                                      index
                                                                                                  )
                                                                                              }
                                                                                          >
                                                                                              Remove
                                                                                          </span>
                                                                                      </button>
                                                                                  </div>
                                                                              </div>
                                                                          </div>
                                                                      )
                                                                  )
                                                                : ""}
                                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to local storage globally. If you set up a listener to detect when local storage is updated, you can call a function to retrieve the items from local storage and set them in cart state immediately. Then, in the cart component, set it to update when the cart state is updated. You can do this with the built-in Context hook, there's no need for redux.

Create a piece of context for the cart state e.g.

```
import { createContext } from 'react'; 

//set initial value of cart to null (pre-adding anything in cart)
export const CartContext = createContext(null);
```

At the top level of your app, e.g. in the App.js file, add the logic to update the cart state. I used some of your code to show the rough idea of what functions should do, of course do whatever manipulations you need and probably put this in a custom hook, not actually leave in App.js:

```
//create cart state 
const [cart, setCart] = useState(null)

// call this when local storage updates
const handleLocalStorage = () => {
   if (localStorage.getItem("cart") !== null) {
      // get the items from local storage 
      cart_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
     // etc. etc., manipulate however you want
     //set items to cart state
     setCart(cart_data);
   }
  return;
}

// listen to local storage in the browser on each render 
useEffect(() => {
     document.addEventListener("storage", handleLocalStorage, true);
     return () => {
     document.removeEventListener("storage", handleLocalStorage, true);
    };
   }); 

// pass the cart state into the context wrapper for the app
return (
<CartContext.Provider value={cart}>
    // app goes here
</CartContext.Provider>

)
```

Finally, in your Cart component you'll have access to the cart state and can pass it the `cart` value to update in real-time whenever it changes.

```
const { cart } = useContext(CartContext)
```

If you're not familiar with the useContext hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Essential for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage won't update unless you refresh the page or add a listener (window.addEventListener("storage")...) inside another component. I think you have to rethink the structure or choose a global state approach.

1. Context API
2. React Redux